# Passing a struct pointer containing NULL all of a sudden contains a struct instead of NULL

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null

OKay I have recreated a smaller example and the problem persists...

Comments indicate whats going on. Expecting the pointer to be NULL but IM getting a struct with NULL values after passing it to another function a second time.

header.h

```
typedef struct node {
int data;
struct node *next;
} *List;
```

source.c

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void two(List *self)
{
    //*self does not = NULL now
    //*self = a struct with null data and next values
}

void one(List *self)
{
    two(&self);
    // *self = 0x0000... NULL
}

int main()
{
    List test = NULL;
    one(&test);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will be allowed `*ThePointer` with struct definition .

Comment: `Sorry I cant show the actual code as it's an assignment.`: We can't help you this way. We need actual code. Furthermore, if you copy-pasted code from one project to another, and the semantics/results are different, then something really funky happened in between, most likely originating from the project's other code.

Comment: I am sorry, not going to try to hack your computer to discover your code and solve your problem. Your code please.

Comment: @ameyCU: BTW, that syntax is valid. Not a very useful one, but it's valid.

Comment: Actually there is a difference...
TheFunction is passing it again to AnotherFunction(&...) in the same way..

Self is becoming un-Nulled in the 2nd pass.

can you only pass it once this way?

and PS didnt copy n past any code... wrote it all new. Just been comparing the 2 project for hours and cant see whats wrong.

Comment: @Brad: ... Great. May we know *all* the code as to find a solution? SO is not a "solve my assignment service". If your instructor doesn't allow you to post the code, it's **precisely** because he wants **you** to solve the problem and not SO to do it. Teachers know about SO's existence, and SO knows about teachers' existence. As a result, SO is not here to replace teachers.

Comment: @ameyCU  It might not be the proper way to typdef lol But thats how they teach it at my uni.

Comment: By definition you don't know where/what the problem is. So it is possible your eyes are not even seeing it and hence likely you are not even describing the actual root issue. So the only way we can help you is if you show code that actually exhibits the problem. It doesn't have to be your actual assignment code. Just some example code that illustrates the problem. You might even find the problem yourself as you construct that minimal example.

Comment: Stop babling, make a MCVE. Maybe just trying to do a MCVE will solve your problem.

Comment: @ameyCU Of course it's allowed.  It's a pointer typedef with an underlying struct type.  This has been supported since the very early days of the C language.  You can use declarators in typedefs, just as you can in variable declarations.

Comment: Hey yeah I know. I dont want you to do my assignment lol. Just thought maybe theirs some obvious thing to look out for that I have not been taught.

I was reluctant to post any code because they have an automated system that checks your code against online sources for plagiarism. And I've heard of people being flagged for plagiarism by their own stack overflow posts.

I'll follow your advice though and create a simple reconstruction and see if I pick it up. If the same error happens again I'll post it.

Comment: OK it's definatly because Im passing into a function then passing it again into yet another function.

Before I pass it the 2nd time if I do
ThePointer test = *self
and then use &test in the 2nd pass it works.
Sorry for the vague useless post.
But the fact that I asked is what helped me solve the problem.
Spent hours trying to work it out before.

Comment: If the code worked last time and doesn't work this time, there must be a significant difference between what you did last time and what you're doing this time — or you got unlucky last time and the undefined behaviour seemed to work, whereas this time you got lucky and it doesn't. Either way, there is nothing we can do to help you while you don't post an MCVE ([MCVE]). It needn't be exactly the same as your homework; it just needs to illustrate the same problem. The code you show must be broken; we will help you fix it. With your abstract discussions and zero code, there is no way we can help.

Comment: @Brad This is a nonsense, I see no reason you could not pass the same pointer as a function argument twice. Maybe there is a memory overflow in your code.

Comment: I have done the MCVE for you guys to see..
(in header.h)
typedef struct node {
 int data;
 struct node *next;
} *List;

(in source.c)
#include "Header.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void two(List *self)
{
 //*self does not = NULL now
 //*self = a struct with null data and next values
}

void one(List *self)
{
 two(&self);
 // *self = 0x0000... NULL
}

int main()
{
 List test = NULL;
 one(&test);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List test = NULL;
one(&test);
```

`test` is a pointer to `struct node`. We pass the address of that
pointer to `one`, allowing `one` to change `test` (letting it return a
new pointer is a cleaner way to do this).

`one` then executes this:

```
two(&self);
```

`two` is now being passed the address of the address of `test`. This is
probably not what you intended. Passing the address of `test` still lets
you change `test` if that's what you want to do:

```
two(self);
```

Comment: Thanx a lot m8. In similar examples we had been passing the address for functions to modify whats already there. But now this assignment kinda requires the modifications to pass through 2 functions. I'm guessing he has done this on purpose to make this problem appear.

I think your right though. Returning a pointer would be a lot better than treating them differently deeper within functions. I was already coming to that conclusion myself but wasn't sure if I was just taking the easy way out because I was just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `one()` function should be:

```
void one(List *self)
{
    two(self);
}
```

Please compile with arguments `-Wall`. Also, it is recommended to use `-Wextra` and `-Werror`.